# Checking if a Cell has value, if it has jumps to the other and writes value

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to do script that when exporting values to sheet if it checks that cell has values it jumps to another row. I can't seem to make it work. The output will always be 2 on the same cell

```
 if  ws1.cell(column=1, row=xrow).value is None:
        sd = ws1.cell(column=1, row=xrow).value
        ws1.cell(column=1, row=xrow).value = 2
    else:
        xrow = xrow + 1
        ws1.cell(column=1, row=xrow).value = 2
    wb.save(dest_filename)
```

Comment: You should look more at the condition you're checking for. Also, use `cell.offset()` if you want another cell that is related positionally.

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood is that you are looking for an empty row to add data if not to just continue.
Below code works for that:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws=wb.active
max_row_val =ws.max_row


col=1
for rows in range(1, max_row_val + 1):
    if ws.cell(rows, col).value == None:
        sd = ws.cell(col, rows).value
        ws.cell(rows,col).value = 2
    elif ws.cell(rows, col).value != None:
        ws.cell(rows, col).value = 2
    rows=rows+1
            
wb.save("file.xlsx")
```